# CSS Dropdown Position Error in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, positioning

Dropdown displays ok in Chrome but not FF?

http://bit.ly/1pjqnPu

Thoughts?

Comment: Would you be able to give us a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) instead?

Comment: You need to add code and quality to your question. As of right now it should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `float:left` on the `<ul>`:

```
<ul id="menu" style="float:left;">
```

becomes:

```
<ul id="menu">
```

Then in your CSS set the `<li>` to `display:block` and `float:left`...

```
.navigation ul li {
    display: block; /* new */
    float: left; /* new */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

... and position the submenu at `top:100%`

```
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; /* amended */
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `left: 0;` to `ul#menu li ul.sub-menu`